# identifier "wstring" is undefined even though I included all the libraries which it was defined in

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm getting an `identifier "wstring" is undefined` error in my cmake project, even though I included the header where it was defined in. I have no idea why this is happening. I am using MSVC.

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <xstring>

int getPID(const char* process)
{
    size_t size = strlen(process);
    wstring procName(process, &process[size]);
    transform(procName.begin(), procName.end(), procName.begin(), ::tolower);
    int pid = -1;
    HANDLE hProcessSnap;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;

    hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return(pid);
    }

    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    if (!Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
        return(pid);
    }

    do
    {
        wstring strProc(pe32.szExeFile);
        transform(strProc.begin(), strProc.end(), strProc.begin(), ::tolower);
        if (strProc == procName)
        {
            return pe32.th32ProcessID;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32));

    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
    return(pid);
}

void SuspendProcess(DWORD processId)
{
    HANDLE hThreadSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);

    THREADENTRY32 threadEntry; 
    threadEntry.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32);

    Thread32First(hThreadSnapshot, &threadEntry);

    do
    {
        if (threadEntry.th32OwnerProcessID == processId)
        {
            HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE,
                threadEntry.th32ThreadID);
            
            SuspendThread(hThread);
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
    } while (Thread32Next(hThreadSnapshot, &threadEntry));

    CloseHandle(hThreadSnapshot);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    
}
```

I tried including `<xstring>` where it was defined in, but it didn't work. I checked this isn't just an IntelliSense error, its a compiler error.

Comment: `wstring procName(process, &process[size]);` -- The `wstring` is in the `std::` namespace.  You could have whittled this down to a very simple [non-working example](https://godbolt.org/z/s9x7Yj4xd).

Comment: thanks for the help I thought if you just include the header directly you don't need to use the "std::" part but I guess the tutorial I watched was wrong

Comment: Instead of watching videos, any good C++ book introduces a "Hello World" program similar to this: `#include <iostream> int main() { std::cout << "Hello World"; }` -- Note the `std::cout`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie regretably most books dont : they teach `#include <iostream>; using namespace std;  int main { cout << "Hello World!"; }` and thus they teach the wrong thing. The wrong think being the `using namespace std;` part which is not recommended

Answer (score 1):

You need to

- use either `std::wstring` instead of `wstring`
- or use `using namespace std;` (not recommended)

And BTW you shouldn't include `<xstring>` which is non standard, but `<string>`.

Comment: thank you for the help I just included xtring because I couldn't get the wstring type to be defined so I looked at which header it was defined in

Comment: Including `<xstring>` happens to work too, but in the future it might not.

Comment: @ZGuardian *I looked at which header it was defined in* -- [See this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).  You will see that `std::wstring` is defined in the `<string>` header.  This is for any standard C++ compiler -- there shouldn't have been any reason to search for an obscure `xstring` header.

Comment: You could also try `using std::wstring;`.